# Eventmachine 1.2.7 refuses to install on Mac m2 ventura 13.2.1

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew, eventmachine

The event machine gem for ruby is trying to install but fails with the following log file
I have tried everything that I have seen online like linking the openssl and running the install with a path attached to it ( I think that's what I did) I think that the problem is that I tried to install it as part of a larger app beef and now it has messed up the directories, because in the rvm/ruby folder there are multiple ruby-3.0.3 directories that like ruby-3.0.3@beef
Thanks in advance

```
urrent directory: /Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20230322-23642-j44qsr.rb extconf.rb --with-cppflags\=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
-----
Using OpenSSL from pkg-config -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include  && -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/lib && -lssl -lcrypto
-----
checking for -lcrypto... yes
checking for -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW in time.h... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: /Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make DESTDIR\=
compiling binder.cpp
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling em.cpp
em.cpp:2119:3: warning: 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                sprintf(errbuf, "failed to register file watch descriptor with kqueue: %s", strerror(errno));
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:188:1: note: 'sprintf' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.")
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:215:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
        #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                      ^
em.cpp:2186:3: warning: 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                sprintf(errbuf, "error registering file %s for watching: %s", fpath, strerror(errno));
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:188:1: note: 'sprintf' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.")
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:215:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
        #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                      ^
em.cpp:2214:3: warning: 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                sprintf(errbuf, "failed to open file %s for registering with kqueue: %s", fpath, strerror(errno));
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:188:1: note: 'sprintf' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.")
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:215:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
        #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                      ^
em.cpp:2365:3: warning: 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                sprintf(errbuf, "failed to register file watch descriptor with kqueue: %s", strerror(errno));
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:188:1: note: 'sprintf' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.")
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:215:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
        #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                      ^
4 warnings generated.
compiling kb.cpp
compiling page.cpp
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp:220:3: warning: 'rb_rescue' is deprecated: Use of ANYARGS in this function is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                rb_rescue((VALUE (*)(ANYARGS))event_callback, (VALUE)&e, (VALUE (*)(ANYARGS))event_error_handler, Qnil);
                ^
/Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/cxxanyargs.hpp:244:1: note: 'rb_rescue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED("Use of ANYARGS in this function is deprecated")
^
/Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/attributes.h:79:35: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED'
#define RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED(mseg) RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED((mseg))
                                  ^
/Users/pkladogenis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/attr/deprecated.h:32:53: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED'
# define RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__ msg))
                                                    ^
1 warning generated.
compiling ssl.cpp
ssl.cpp:216:9: warning: 'PEM_read_bio_DHparams' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        dh = PEM_read_bio_DHparams(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                             ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/pem.h:472:21: note: 'PEM_read_bio_DHparams' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DECLARE_PEM_rw_attr(OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0, DHparams, DH)
                    ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:193:49: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0'
#   define OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0                OSSL_DEPRECATED(3.0)
                                                ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
ssl.cpp:227:4: warning: 'DH_free' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        DH_free(dh);
                        ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/dh.h:203:1: note: 'DH_free' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DH_free(DH *dh);
^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:193:49: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0'
#   define OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0                OSSL_DEPRECATED(3.0)
                                                ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
ssl.cpp:243:12: warning: 'EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(nid);
                                       ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/ec.h:1001:1: note: 'EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 EC_KEY *EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(int nid);
^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:193:49: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0'
#   define OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0                OSSL_DEPRECATED(3.0)
                                                ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
ssl.cpp:254:5: warning: 'EC_KEY_free' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                EC_KEY_free(ecdh);
                                ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/ec.h:1006:1: note: 'EC_KEY_free' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void EC_KEY_free(EC_KEY *key);
^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:193:49: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0'
#   define OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0                OSSL_DEPRECATED(3.0)
                                                ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
4 warnings generated.
linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.bundle
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SSL_get1_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPeerCert() in ssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2


I Have tried linking the openssl with brew and it did but it didn't seem to fix anything
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same problem on my Mac m2 ventura 13.2.1.

it seems you have `openssl@3` but needs `openssl@1.1`.
so, The following command might help:

```
brew uninstall openssl@3
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Comment: You can have multiple openssl version installed, there's no need to remove v3